# ffmpeg -f sdl compares to ffmpeg -f h264 via UDP

Tags: ffmpeg

I am very new to ffmpeg, and want to ask in ffmpeg -f sdl, what is the force format means and what is sdl?

I'm asking this because, when I try

> ffmpeg -i udp://192.168.1.124:12345 -f h264 "test"
>
> ffmpeg -i udp://192.168.1.124:12345 -f sdl "test"

if I use -f h264, it seems just receiving the stream and save to file "test"

however if I use -f sdl, it seems it will not store to a file, instead, it brings up a video player view and start playing the video directly.

however, this didn't make me think it has anything to do with force format(-f)?

I couldn't find the doc on https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-formats.html. Can someone help on this? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FFmpeg can write data to structured containers (AVI/MP4/MKV..) or raw streams (H264,M4V..) or devices (Decklink/SDL..). All of these are specified using `-f`. For file-based output, they are usually inferred via the extension, so `-f` can be omitted.

SDL2 is the library used by ffplay to render textures to display and also catch input keyboard/mouse events. If ffmpeg was compiled alongwith ffplay, SDL2 is linked with ffmpeg binary as well. But with ffmpeg, only video is rendered.